# remove an list Item using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a script which is using jQuery drag and drop.

Using that I am moving items between two lists. I am able to add items using `append` function but , `jQuery` `remove` is not working .

```
 $("#dvright").on('drop', function (evt) {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    var data = evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
                    var lst = $("#lstselectedproducts");
                    var li = "<li>" + data + "</li>";
                    li.textContent = data;
                    lst.append(li);

                    var lstSrc = $("#lstproducts");

//This is where I am expecting to remove the item from source list.
                        lstSrc.remove(data);

                    });
```

Comment: What is `data`? A simple text? This won't work as `remove()` expects a selector expression.

Comment: @Paulpro , tried using lstSrc[0].removeChild(li), it's not removing.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy, What should I pass as a selector

Comment: @Simsons I just realized you have two separate lists, `lst` and `lstSrc`.

Comment: @Paulpro, Yes, lst is where I am adding/appending items and lstSrc , remove items once appended on lst.

Comment: @Simons `removeChild(li)` is not working as `li` is not a child of `lstSrc`. I see that you are currently fetching the text only. You need to somehow pass  a unique value to identify the source `li`. Then you can write something like `lstSrc.find(selector).remove()`. Basically what we need is more info about the HTML structure of the source list.

Answer (score 2):

Add Class to `li` `class="item"`

```js
$(document).on('click','.item',function(){
$(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>

<li class="item">item 1</li>
<li class="item">item 2</li>
<li class="item">item 3</li>
<li class="item">item 4</li>
<li class="item">item 5</li>

</ul>
```